# $lookup is super slow despite the from collection being empty

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongodb-indexes

The base collection has 100,000 documents. All of which will be run through a `$lookup` stage. The collection that will be looked up in is empty.

This query takes 30 seconds.

When I remove the `$lookup` stage, this query takes 3 seconds.

What explains why it is so slow, despite the foreign collection be empty, having no documents?

Even if it has documents, there is an index for the pipeline.

EDITED:

The `$lookup` is dynamic, which means that it needs to match on a different value for each of the 100,000 documents.

bits of the explain():

```
      "$lookup": {
         from: ....
      },
      ....           
      "totalDocsExamined": 0,
      "totalKeysExamined": 0,
      "collectionScans": 0,
      "indexesUsed": [
        "A_1_B_1_C_1"
      ],
      "nReturned": 100000,
      "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 35602
    },
```

Comment: What is the query?

Comment: What is the explain plan?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit, I have added the explain plan for the $lookup bit

Comment: @CharchitKapoor, it is a dynamic lookup, meaning each document looks up based on a different value

Answer (score 2):

The `explain plan` clearly states that the time taken is around `35` seconds and the documents returned are `100000`.

One reason behind this is that `$lookup` is evaluated for each and every document of the base collection. Even though the joined collection is empty, the `lookup` will still happen for each document, and there aren't any internal query optimizations possible in this case. The only thing you can do is filter some documents using `$match` before `$lookup`. Joining one complete collection with another using `$lookup`, will not scale as the collections grow in size.